# What is wrong? Probability that no RV is larger than x.

Tags: combinatorics, statistics

Consider $n$ exponentially and independently distributed RVs with mean $1/\lambda$. What is the probability that no RV is larger than $x$?

1. Argument:
   The probability that $n$ RVs are smaller than $x$ is given by the n-th power of the CDF: $(1 - e^{-x \lambda})^n.$
2. Argument:
   A RV is greater than $x$ with probability $\int_x^\infty \lambda e^{-\lambda u} du=e^{-\lambda x}$. Hence, the expected number of RVs that are greater than $x$ is $n e^{-\lambda x}$. Consequently, the probability that no RV is greater than $x$ is
   $e^{-n e^{-\lambda x}}$ assuming that the expected number of RVs that are greater than $x$ is Poisson distributed with mean $n e^{-\lambda x}$.

Now, $(1 - e^{-x \lambda})^n$ and $e^{-n e^{-\lambda x}}$ are not the same. Why is that the case? Is the expected number of RVs that are greater than $x$ not Poisson distributed? If so, why? I'm struggling to understand, why the first first argument is correct but not the 2nd one.

Comment: Why do you think probability none less than x would be related in any way to the expected number less or greater than x?

Comment: Sorry, I don't get your question. Could you elaborate?

Comment: First of all, nothing is said whether random variables are independent or not.

Comment: They are. Made an edit

Comment: @HighwayJohn Prob none less than x is same as prob all are at least x. But expected value is the average of the results (weighted by probability of each). These two things are not in general related for a random variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 2, your *"assuming that the expected number of RVs that are greater than $x$ is Poisson distributed"* seems wrong (and perhaps poorly worded: I doubt it should say "expected") given that the number cannot be more than all of them, i.e. cannot exceed $n$, while there is no upper bound to possible values from a Poisson distribution.

Instead you should be using a binomial distribution with parameters $n$ for the number of cases and $p=e^{-\lambda x}$ for the probability each exceeds $x$.  From the binomial distribution, you get a mean of $ne^{-\lambda x}$ and a probability of the number being zero of ${n \choose 0}p^0(1-p)^{n-0}=(1-e^{-\lambda x})^n$, as 1 says more efficiently.

Comment: Thank you! That was very helpful